Going to the direcory of a file as fast as posible
Is there a way to get to the path of a file as fast as possible and in the least amount of keystrokes.
Context:
Type cd and then paste the path of a file and then have to go back and hit backspace until the path reflects a directory.
I'm think of something like <cd> directory/directory2/file.file and it takes me to directory2, maybe even something like Ctrl+w just that only deletes "file.file", I know that cd is part of the shell, I'm currently switching from bash to zsh, so if the answer is zsh friendly it would be even better.

In both bash and zsh, I think C-r / C-k is the fewest keystrokes that works out of box for all file names regardless of word constituent settings. If the file base name only consists of word constituents and / isn't a word constituent in your configuration then M-BkSp C-K is fewer keystrokes (but perhaps as much typing anyway).
